# Merge separate ReactJS client frontend application with ASP.NET Core backend API?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core

I'm developing a full-stack web application with an ASP.NET Core back-end that serves REST & GraphQL APIs. The .NET Core app is structured the following way in Visual Studio:

```
Backend.API: the API portion of the project that contains all the controllers and GraphQL query/mutation definitions that the front-end application consumes.  
Backend.Core: the portion of the back-end that defines all the user & application models used by the Backend.Data portion.  
Backend.Data: interacts with the database and defines all the repositories that the Backend.API portion uses when returning data for GraphQL queries, etc.
```

The back-end .NET Core APIs are consumed by a front-end ReactJS application that is entirely separate from the C# Project (created as a separate ReactJS app).

I didn't want to use the ReactJS ASP.NET Core template as I wanted to maintain a separation of concerns between front- and back-end, which a template like that would have blurred. So far, I've been able to allow the front-end ReactJS application to consume the backend ASP.NET Core API by providing the localhost URL the back-end launches on (i.e. the ReactJS app launches on localhost:3000 and fetches from API endpoints on localhost:5437 where the back-end is launched by Visual Studio). However, this separation between the two portions isn't feasible when I want to, for example, deploy the website--I need to combine the front-end and back-end projects so that they operate under the same URL.

Therefore, this poses the question: what's the best way to merge my separate front-end ReactJS app with my back-end ASP.NET Core API so that they operate under a single URL?

Comment: Do you use React-Router?

Comment: Yes, the ReactJS frontend uses React Router, along with Redux and Apollo GraphQL.

Comment: What is the longest chain in the routing hierarchy? (/resources/1/edit etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do in case I were in your place:

1. I would rename Backend.API to Backend.Web
2. Move my entire react app into the `wwwroot` folder
3. Create a middleware which will serve my React's app `index.html` page

   :

   ```
         app.Use(async (context, next) =>
         {
           await next();
           var path = context.Request.Path.Value;

           if (!path.StartsWith("/api") && !Path.HasExtension(path))
           {
             context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
             await next();
           }
         });
   ```

   4. Be sure you have the middleware for default files and static files included in the pipeline:

   `app.UseDefaultFiles();
   app.UseStaticFiles();`
4. Index.html would link the JavaScript and CSS created after the ReactJS application is build.

Comment: This solution seems to work. However, it seems that you can also use app.UseSpa() in Startup.cs along with the proper configuration, based on the React ASP.NET Core template.